# How to make NSButton as Default without title bar to its window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I want to make `NSButton` as a 'Default' button so that when i hit "Enter" key that button gets clicked(i.e its Click Action gets called), i am able to do it by setting its key Equivalent to '\r' or by hitting 'Enter' key in Xib.

But in case if the same window does not have title bar, then default button does not work.

I have tried by making myWindow borderless programitcally

```
[mywindow setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

still it does not help.

So my question is how to make NSButton as 'Default' Button without title bar to its Window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Window_Style_Masks):

> A window that uses NSBorderlessWindowMask can’t become key or main,
>   unless you implement canBecomeKeyWindow or canBecomeMainWindow to
>   return YES

Subclass `NSWindow` and implement `canBecomeKeyWindow` or `canBecomeMainWindow` to make `NSButton` as 'Default' Button without title bar Window.

```
@interface PBWindow : NSWindow

@end
@implementation PBWindow

-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Set NSWindow class name to PBWindow:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try programmatically below:-

```
NSRect myRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 1, 1);
NSButton *defaultButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];

[defaultButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];
[defaultButton setTarget:self];
[defaultButton setAction:@selector(yourActionMethod:)];
[[self view] addSubview:defaultButton];
[defaultButton release];
```